# It asks to get a term of Fibonacci sequence.Can't make out why my code always gets timeout

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, fibonacci

It's an issue in Hackerrank.The link is here:[fibonacci-finding-easy](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fibonacci-finding-easy)

It gives two initial values F(0),F(1) of the recursive sequence F(n+2)=F(n+1)+F(n) and assigns them to A,B respectively and asks for the Nth item of it,output it modulo (10^9 + 7).I know the classic way to solve is using quick matrix multiplication.And I write it in Python3.The tests in my IDE have no problems.But I don't know why my code always gets timeout.Here is my code:

```
def mul22(a, b):
    r = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
    r[0][0] = (a[0][0] * b[0][0] + a[0][1] * b[1][0]) % 1000000007
    r[0][1] = (a[0][0] * b[0][1] + a[0][1] * b[1][1]) % 1000000007
    r[1][0] = (a[1][0] * b[0][0] + a[1][1] * b[1][0]) % 1000000007
    r[1][1] = (a[1][0] * b[0][1] + a[1][1] * b[1][1]) % 1000000007
    return r

def MatrixPow(A, n):
    if n == 1:
        return A
    if n % 2 == 1:
        return mul22(mul22(MatrixPow(A, n // 2),MatrixPow(A, n // 2)), A)
    return mul22(MatrixPow(A, n // 2), MatrixPow(A, n // 2))

for i in range(int(input())):
    A,B,N= map(int,input().split())
    if N == 1:
        print(B % 1000000007)
    else:
        print(mul22(MatrixPow([[1, 1],[1, 0]], N - 1),[[B,1],[A,1]])[0][0] % 1000000007)
```

In the first place I think the problem is that 10 ** 9 + 7 makes the whole recursive process so slow.But I test many times in my IDE and everything is okay,there exists no TLEs.Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have written the `MatrixPow` function, it is not actually running in `O(log(n))`. Its running time is `O(N)`.

Consider this power function:

```
def power_n(a,b):
    print 1
    if b==0:
        return 1
    if b%2==1:
        return (((power_n(a,b/2)*power_n(a,b/2))%MOD)*a)%MOD
    return (power_n(a,b/2)*power_n(a,b/2))%MOD
```

and this:

```
def power_log(a,b):
    print 2
    if b==0:
        return 1
    k = power_log(a,b/2)
    if b%2==1:
        return (((k*k)%MOD)*a)%MOD
    return (k*k)%MOD
```

The difference in 1st and second is that we are going through the whole recursion tree only once in second case (as once we have a certain value, we save it) while in 1st case, we calculate it again and again.

Though they seem to be the same, the 1st one is similar to traditional loop and runs in O(n) while the 2nd function is actually the power function which runs in O(log n)

PS: `n` means `b`, ie. the power

EDIT:

Analysis:
(I just added a print statement to both the functions and ran it, here is the result)

```
power_n(6,20)
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    Out[22]: 414469870

power_log(6,20)
    2
    2
    2
    2
    2
    2
    Out[25]: 414469870
```

See the difference in number of times the function is called.

Comment: I have updated my code as above.But nothing change.Is it wrong?If not,maybe it's Hackerrank's problem.

Comment: Ye,it passed all tests instantly.Just as you said,I made k = MatrixPow(A, n // 2) and avoided repeated calculations.

Comment: Yep...that's it :)